# When (if) are we going to have keyboard shortcuts for comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, usability, keyboard-shortcuts

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14756/189165) wasasked in 2009, four years ago. Most [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14761/189165) are [given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80386/189165) in the same period of time and no later than on 2011 (two years ago or more) and ... do we have any progress on this?

When (if at all) can we expect to have such obvious, fundamental functionality implemented in SE net?

If not, is there any source, with *reasonable reasons*, explaining, why we can't have keyboard shortcuts for comments? All answers or votes for not implementing this, I found so far, are from weak to very weak (abuse?) and does not convince me at all.

And no, using a [Greasemonkey script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2103/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-comments) isn't a wise solution (why don't we use it for questions & answers, if it is that good, huh?). I actually find the situation, where keyboard shortcuts works for Q&A and are disabled  for comments, one of the worst feature of SE network. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Comments are *meant* to be second class citizens: they are transient, unprotected, possessed of only weak choices in formatting, and otherwise the red-headed step-children of the network.

This is policy.

The odds are that you are *never* going to get such a feature, because the team doesn't want you writing a lot of fancy stuff in comments unless it is *very* important.

Comment: Doesn't mean they should have bad UX.

Comment: Also while there is truth to your first argument that point is wildly abused. Comments are very often necessary. Good comments are encouraged. We *explicitly* encourage downvoters to leave a comment. Do you realize that right now it's possible to downvote by keyboard but not explain your downvote by keyboard?

Comment: I have a bad feeling, that we are talking about two completely different things! I'm saying, that not having keyboard shortcuts in comments is very unhandy. You're replying with a list of arguments, why we shouldn't use formatting in comments at all. While these arguments are true, it doesn't change the picture. If you (dev team) think, that comments should not have formatting, then **remove this feature entirely** and leave just the plain text. If you give us formatting, than don't take us ease of using it, and give us keyboard shortcuts as well.

Comment: Do you _really_ believe that blocking keyboard shortcuts in comments will stop users from using formatting there? These are two separate things! It's like saying "_I'll remove gas pedal from your car, because you shouldn't drive too fast! Use your feet only (like George Flinstone) to accelerate your car_". Also, take a look at [this, quite similar answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99274/189165) and my comment to it.

Comment: @trejder The thing to remember is that the team is constantly busy. They are always working on *something* and they have to prioritize. There is nothing wrong with this idea; it would be nice. But, I'll give you long odd that the team places technical debt ahead of this which basically means that they'll get to it the Tuesday before Hell freezes over.