# Autosave comment as a draft or display some warning upon leaving the page

Tags: feature-request, comments

This has happened to me a few times: I start writing a comment, then close the tab or follow some links without having finished to write the comment, thereby losing my draft. Sometimes my browser decides to crash too, or I need to leave before having the time to finish writing the comment.

How about autosaving comments as drafts or display some warning upon leaving the page as we do for [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1177/178179)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks, I think about warning is a bit more annoying, while autosaving shouldn't annoy users who take less than twenty seconds to write a comment.

Comment: Autosaving is lots of work, warning is instant. Best we can hope for is a warning, as comments are not important enough.

Comment: I would have expected that autosaving comments would use a technology similar to autosaving questions. At worst draft comments could even be saved in the client's local storage, that should be straightforward to do.

Answer (score -1):

Comments are not supposed to be important. They should take you twenty seconds to write and ought to just clarify some aspect of the question or answer.

As a result, I don't see why they need draft capabilities. Drafts are only necessary when your risk losing important text that you've taken some time to write (e.g. a question or answer).

Comment: Unless there are 3 links in that comment, which you spent 10 minutes searching for.