# Prompt before closing browser tab if comment has not been submitted

Tags: feature-request, comments

If I am working on a post, and try to close the browser window, then a prompt is displayed asking if I want to leave the page.

However, the same thing does not happen if I am working on a comment.

I am proposing **extending the "navigate away" prompt to include the situation where there is a comment on the page that has not yet been saved** (either a new comment, or one that is being edited, which has a non-zero length).

Comment: If the comment is so important, perhaps it shouldn't be a comment...

Comment: @Catija sometimes even losing 20 characters cause frustration.

Comment: @Catija Except perhaps in cases like when you have spent some time to find relevant resources to help a newcomer improve their question, and manage to close the wrong browser tab. See for example the reasoning in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234335/157730.

Comment: @ShadowWizard 20 characters should be easily replicable...

Comment: If you're improving an answer, it should be an edit, not a comment.

Comment: @Catija I shouldn't be editing someone else's post if I don't know what the intent of the original poster is.

Comment: @Catija it is about user experience. Even if something isn't that important, having to repeat it is not pleasant. If the change would have required lots of development and efforts, I'd also be against it due to the nature of comments, being "third class citizens". However, being a simple thing to implement, I think it would be nice to have.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Considering I'm more likely to intentionally close a window/navigate away without submitting a comment... this would make my UE worse.

Comment: @Catija Please read my question (proposal) again. This is for situations where you are **actively doing something with the new/edit comment field.** If I click "add a comment" below a post *and type something,* then I probably intend to submit that comment.

Comment: @Catija in that case, adding a "cancel" link when adding a comment might be a required change as well. (There is already one when editing)

Comment: I'm fully capable of reading... I mean that I often enter text into the comment field and then decide not to submit it because I find it to be a poor choice to add to the conversation... Sometimes it's cathartic to write something out but never hit send.

Comment: @Catija I also do that sometimes, but even more with answers. So it shouldn't be what's stopping such a feature from being done.

Comment: This is a [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](http://stackapps.com/q/6091/26088) feature BTW ;) But I do agree that SE should add the alert themselves!